# How to lock my session as soon as I login?

Tags: boot, gnome, manjaro, fish

I'm on Manjaro Gnome (using [fish](https://fishshell.com/)) and I want to enable Automatic Login and then force the session to lock. The idea being that I can boot and walk away from my computer, knowing that it will continue loading everything I need to get started (I have a heavy startup sequence—a *mise en place* for my work, if you will).

After some research, I tried adding the following:

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver \
          /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock
```

to `~/.xinitrc` and `~/.profile`, but I'm clearly missing something, as neither worked. What's the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [desktop file](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) in `~/.config/autostart` with just a single command `xlock` or the one you're showing here.

An example could be:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=1.0
Name=Autolock
Comment=Locks the screen after login
Exec=xlock
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! Here's how I tried to follow your suggestion, but no luck: `vim ~/.config/autostart/lock.desktop` then type `xlock` into the file, then save and reboot. The system just logs in, no lock happens.

Comment: You don't just type `xlock` into the desktop file. I've provided the link for reference. There must be other files in this directory - you may also check them.

Comment: @Stewart Thanks!

Comment: The `xlock` entry didn't work (and when I type `xlock` in the Terminal, it says that command doesn't exist). I'll have to step away for a bit, but I'll try adding the `dbus` command in the `Exec` section. Thanks for the help so far :).

Comment: @Khashir `xlockmore` is part of the `xlockmore` package. It's such a handy small utility it makes sense to have it installed at least if you're using a classic X11/X.org session. It might not work under Wayland.

Comment: Hey, this worked like a charm—thanks Artem :) (and @Stewart)!